[Credential Manager]Automatic login won't select the last account used when multiple Google accounts are present
I'm trying to use Google sign-in, referring to the documentation.
https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg
The document mentions that calling the "setAutoSelectEnabled(true)" function can achieve automatic login, but I have found that when multiple Google accounts exist and have all been logged in previously, even if the logout function "clearCredentialState()" has been invoked for other accounts, a manual selection of an account is still required for login every time.
Here is the snippet of my code for the automatic login section.
enter image description here
Here is my SDK version.
enter image description here
Does anyone have a better solution?
I would like to know if it can automatically select and log in with the account that was not logged out last time, or directly obtain the previously logged-in idtoken to replace the automatic login process.

Please post all code and other text as formatted text instead of as images.

If there are more than one Google accounts that have the grants for your app (that is, user had previously used both of them to sign into your app), then we do not pick any in favor of the other one since we don't know which one user really wants to use (since both have been used in the past), hence we do not do an auto sign-in.

Thank you very much for your reply. I understand your intention to allow users to choose one of their Google accounts to log in. However, as described in the question, all other accounts of the user have been logged out previously, and only the last used account remains logged in. Could we perhaps consider that the user has implicitly made a choice by this action?

We have previously used Facebook login as well, and according to Facebook's documentation, they support this approach. As long as Facebook users do not log out or their accounts are not considered expired by Facebook, they can directly use the previously used account to log in.@Ali Naddaf

When you said user has logged out of the other accounts, what does that exactly mean?

What I meant was call the API 'clearCredentialState()'. Please refer to this section of the documentation: https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg#handle-sign-out. After our app users log in with Google, a logout button will be provided within the app. When users click on it, we will call the 'clearCredentialState()'. @Ali Naddaf

Thanks 胡全壮. Let me think about it and see what we can do to help with this situation.

You're welcome, and thank you for patiently answering my questions.
